# postgres chooses an aweful query plan , how can that be fixed

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to optimize this query :

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE  
select
  dtt.matching_protein_seq_ids
from detected_transcript_translation dtt
join peptide_spectrum_match psm 
    on psm.detected_transcript_translation_id = 
       dtt.detected_transcript_translation_id
join peptide_spectrum_match_sequence psms 
    on  psm.peptide_spectrum_match_sequence_id = 
       psms.peptide_spectrum_match_sequence_id
WHERE
dtt.matching_protein_seq_ids && ARRAY[654819, 294711]
;
```

When seq_scan are allowed (set enable_seqscan = on), the optimizer chooses a pretty awful plan that runs in 49.85 seconds :

https://explain.depesz.com/s/WKbew

With set enable_seqscan = off, the plan chosen uses proper indexes and the query runs instantely.

https://explain.depesz.com/s/ISHV

note that I did run a ANALYZE on all three tables...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that PostgreSQL cannot estimate the `WHERE` condition well, so it estimates it as a certain percentage of the estimated total rows, which is way too much.

If you *know*  that there will always few result rows for a query like this, you could cheat by defining a function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION matching_transcript_translations(integer[])
   RETURNS SETOF detected_transcript_translation
   LANGUAGE SQL
   STABLE STRICT
   ROWS 2  /* pretend there are always exactly two matching rows */
AS
'SELECT * FROM detected_transcript_translation
   WHERE matching_protein_seq_ids && $1';
```

You could use that like

```
select
  dtt.matching_protein_seq_ids
from matching_transcript_translations(ARRAY[654819, 294711]) dtt
join peptide_spectrum_match psm 
    on psm.detected_transcript_translation_id = 
       dtt.detected_transcript_translation_id
join peptide_spectrum_match_sequence psms 
    on  psm.peptide_spectrum_match_sequence_id = 
       psms.peptide_spectrum_match_sequence_id;
```

Then PostgreSQL should be cheated into thinking that there will be exactly one matching row.

However, if there are a lot of matching rows, the resulting plan will be even worse than your current plan is…